# How to get connected Mobile Details when that mobile connect using Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

If we have one application we install application in our mobile and when any device connect using Bluetooth we will get that mobile details like Bluetooth Address , IMEI ?

can anyone help me for that ?

Answer (score 0):

whnever you connected with two devices using bluetooth than get the IMEI number of device with the following code:

```
       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

and also you need permission in android manifest file :

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and also check the link for bluetooth example:

http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/